# Adding vibrancy to existing view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I am rather new to Swift and currently trying to achieve a modal with a Blur and Vibrancy effect.

```
let modalViewController = FavoritesViewController()
modalViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .OverFullScreen
self.presentViewController(modalViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This is how I create the Modal View Controller, which then executes the following `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Instantiate a view from the FavoritesView.xib and add
    // it to this Controller's view
    let optionsView = UINib(nibName: "FavoritesView", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as UIView
    view.addSubview(optionsView)

    // Create a UIVisualEffectView with a blur effect and
    // insert it to this Controller's view
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .Dark)
    let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurView.frame = self.view.bounds
    blurView.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleWidth | .FlexibleHeight
    blurView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(true)
    view.insertSubview(blurView, atIndex: 0)

    // Create a UIVisualEffectView with a vibrancy effect
    let vibrancyView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIVibrancyEffect(forBlurEffect: blurEffect))
    vibrancyView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    vibrancyView.contentView.addSubview(optionsView) 
    // This is the part I'm unsure of.

    blurView.contentView.addSubview(vibrancyView)
}
```

With this code the blur is created and shown, but the vibrancy doesn't seem to work. From what I understand, first `optionsView` (which is the modal view containing labels and buttons) is added to the Controller's view, then the blur is being inserted behind it.

Finally the Vibrancy View gets created, the `optionsView` gets added to the vibrancy view's `contentView` (I assume this is necessary, so that the vibrancy effect can get applied to the views labels and such). This Vibrancy View then gets added to the blurView.

However, labels and buttons still don't show up with the vibrancy effect applied. Do I need to make any adjustments to the UI elements in the `.xib`-file in order for the Vibrancy to be applied or should it be applied automatically? Or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

Hi just try it on `viewWillAppear`

`viewDidLoad` isn't the right place for elements on screen (`UIView` and so on..)

Comment: It still doesn't apply the vibrancy effect. The view is also not present in `viewDidLoad`, because it's being loaded from an additional .xib via UINib instantiateWithOwner. The line `vibrancyView.contentView.addSubview(optionsView)` kills it. Without it, the view is being displayed with a blurry background (just like intended), but with it, nothing is displayed at all.